# The area of the quadrilateral whose vertices are $(2,1)$....

Tags: analytic-geometry

The area of the quadrilateral whose vertices are $(2,1)$, $(-1,3)$, $(-3,-1)$ and $(3,-4)$ is

My attempt:

I guess the area of quadrilateral 
$$=\dfrac {1}{2} |x_1y_2 - x_2y_1 + x_2y_3 -x_3y_2 +x_3y_4-x_4y_3 +x_4y_1 - x_1y_4|$$.

An I right ?

Comment: What are the $x_i$ and $y_i$ ? And why do you think this is the area ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. $A_i=(x_i,y_i)$ are vertices of the given quadrilateral.

Comment: @Astyx, $x$ and $y$ are the co ordinates of the vertices of quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula), of course. Or you may prove it:
[image]

The area of the given quadrilateral is clearly
$$ 6\cdot 7-\left(4+3+2+\frac{5}{2}+9\right) = \color{red}{\frac{43}{2}}.$$

You may also apply [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem):
$$ [ABCD] = \color{purple}{19}+\frac{\color{red}{7}}{2}-1.$$